# Dynamically Setting a List View on a WebPart Page

Tags: client-object-model, list-view, content-editor-web-part, gantt-view

I have been unable to load a page showing a dynamicaly selected View. I can not just display the List itself (Although this would allow me to specify the View in the URL)  because I need to modify aspects of the List via a CEWP on the same page. (I dont have access to SD where I work)

So, I tried to implement this code.  It runs the onQuerySucceeded() function indicating it worked, but no the View displayed is not the "EOM Run" view.

```
...
existingview = viewcollection.getByTitle("EOM Run"); 
clientContext.load(existingview); 

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)); 
}
```

I tried to implement this example: http://www.avanadeblog.com/sharepointasg/2012/03/client-object-model-changing-list-views.html

I dont know what I am missing?